# Intermittent fasting spacing between meals

Tags: intermittent-fasting

I have a question about IF, the fasting part is easy, do not eat... but lets say i only eat from 15:00 to 21:00...

Does it matter if i eat every 2 hours (3 times)? 15:00, 17:00, 19:00
Would be better to eat at 15:00 then at 19:00?
What happens if i eat non stop during this 6 hours? (but still counting calories), does it affect insulin or something that prevents me from burning fat?

Answer (score 2):

6 hour feeding window is pretty good!

Most, if not all, benefit from the intermittent fasting will come from the time period when you don't eat. So, it doesn't really matter how you eat within those 6 hours, as long as the food quality and total food eaten are accounted for.

Concentrate on the quality of food and consistency of the amount and eating window. Don't worry how many time you eat during that window.

Answer (score 0):

The main point of the IF is the *fasting during the fasting period* and **not** the *fasting during the eating period*. As such, the most important part (besides sticking to the fasting window) is what you eat in the eating window (i.e. macros, calories etc.), and less so when you do.